# Can roku Support WebRTC Streams

Tags: webrtc, roku, brightscript

I found this question is [here](https://community.roku.com/t5/Roku-Developer-Program/Can-roku-play-webrtc-streams/m-p/499334#M42606) two years ago. But no one replied. Does anyone know Roku Supports the WebRTC and Play WebRTC Stream. or does it require any External library or API?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Roku's documentation](https://partnersuccess.roku.com/hc/en-us/articles/360060167853-Does-Roku-support-WebRTC-and-Play-WebRTC-streams-), they do not currently support this.